# How to display New product in home page slider? Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, home-page, slider

Can you please help to display new product/Sale product on home page slider.

on my website only out of stock old product coming. I just want to hide the out of stock products from Home page slider.

**magento 1.9**

Comment: Are you use homepage slider of rwd theme?

Comment: Your question seems to be incomplete. Please mention your code you are using to get the product collection.